# Serializing xml in C# with multiple namespaces having the same uri but different prefixes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, namespaces

I need to submit an xml file to a service I don't have any control over so it has to be formatted exactly as specified or it will be rejected, the particular formatting problem I'm having is adding multiple namespaces to the file with the same URI but different prefixes, the end result must look exactly like this:

```
<RootElement xmlns="http://www.example.com/example"  
             xmlns:prefix="http://www.example.com/example">
```

or it will be automatically rejected.

I've tried using the `XmlSerializerNamespaces` class with my `XmlSerializer` to add both namespaces like this:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add(String.Empty,"http://www.example.com/example");
ns.Add("prefix", "http://www.example.com/example");
```

but as long as the URI is the same only one is added, if I change the second URI both elements are added.

EDIT: For anyone looking to solve this or a similar problem in the future, the trivial way to make these very specifically formatted xml files is to use the XMLDocument class instead of the XDocument class. XDocument will try to fix your formatting but XMLDocument will let you do things "wrong" if your web service requires it.

Comment: I was able to get the result I needed by making an XDocument with the XmlSerializer and then adding the namespace to the root element manually which will probably be good enough in this case, however if anyone knows how I could get this to work as part of the initial serialization as I originally intended I'd be interested to hear it.

Comment: Do you want to use same URI but use different prefixes? With 'Serialize' c# class?